# Compare a single value against multiple values in single column with in_array()

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple values saved in one column like this 3,4;3,7;3,12... separated with ; I know it is a bad solutions having multiple values with comma in one column
but can't help it at his point.

I need to compare each value in $value1 '3,4' and '3,7' and '3,12... and so on against another value $compare. If $compare is in $value1 I need to print a row or if it is not - a message.

I have tested mysql querys and they work just fine. Also $value1 prints string correctly. I get no errors but the script always prints the message "Nothing" no matter what value $compare is.

Sorry if some terms are incorrect. I'm a total noob. Thanks!

My code:

```
> <?php  
>
> $compare = 3,4; 
> 
> while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
> 
>       {
> 
>       $value1 = $row['value1'];
>                       $value_single = array_map('trim', explode(';', $value1));
>                       if (in_array('$compare', $value_single))
>               
>               {
>               
>               echo $row['value2'];                    
>       
>               }
>               else
>               
>               {
>                   
>               echo "Nothing";
>                   
>               }
>       
>           
> 
> 
>   }
> 
> ?>
```

Comment: how can it not be helped? secondly 3,4 and '3,4' are two different thinggs thats why you always hit the else. Also space your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

One quoted string `'$compare'` not parse the $compare variable, use `$compare` or double quoted `"$compare"` if need parse variable in string.

You use it here `in_array('$compare', $value_single)` and script tryes to find **$compare** string but not `$compare` value.